Removing inline module script *immediately* after execution?
Since inline module scripts don't have document.currentScript, we can't simply append document.currentScript.remove() at the end of the script.
Extra Notes/Context:

I'm talking about the synchronous phase of the module script's execution. I.e. once the script has synchronously executed, it should immediately be deleted, without e.g. waiting for an event loop tick in which other code might run.
I'm adding the module script to the DOM programmatically, and I don't control the code inside the script tag (i.e. it's "userland" code), or whether or not it's a module script, and so on. I can only do simple modifications to the script that don't affect the code - e.g. appending document.currentScript.remove() would be fine, but e.g. wrapping the script in a function/block scope, or something like that would materially affect the code (e.g. variable scoping), so I can't do stuff like that.
This is an unusual requirement, I must admit, but it's an unusual use case - related to dev tooling / live debugging / etc.


I don’t think there’s any good way to do this, but I’m following this question because I hope someone has an amazing hack to pull it off.

Why after the execution? You may actually want to consider prepending the removal code, so that it runs even in case of an exception (without having to use try/finally, which would be one of the modifications you want to avoid).

Why are you running the code using an inline <script> at all? There are other ways of running code, like eval(…) or import('data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,'+…).

@Bergi "Why after the execution? You may actually want to consider prepending the removal code" Excellent point! Except in case of syntax error I guess. RE use of script tag, this was bc it needs to run after a previous module script that was just added to the DOM, and the only way I could think to do that was to add another module script (which IIUC, will not necessarily run sync, but is guaranteed to run after any prev added module tags). I'm slightly over my head here, so it's possible there are more simple solutions that I'm not considering, but my constraints are a bit unusual/tricky.

Ah, yes, probably needs onerror="this.remove()" as well. How are the "previous module scripts […] added to the DOM", and what code do they contain? Do they use defer? If you're looking for alternative solutions as well, you probably should ask a new question where you state your actual constraints.

@Bergi traktor's answer (+ your improvement suggestion) actually gets me far enough for this specific use case. RE onerror, unfortunately inline script tags don't seem to respect that attribute.

You could try assigning a class or id to the user script and use it to remove the script.


let uniqueClass = "_userlandscript" + Math.random().toString().replace(".", "");

let code = `console.log("hello folks and world");`;

// Append self-deletion snippet:
code +=  `
document.querySelector('.${uniqueClass}').remove();
console.log("Exists:", document.querySelector('.${uniqueClass}'));`;

let script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = code;
script.type = "module";
script.classList.add(uniqueClass);
document.body.append(script);



As noted by @Bergi, you may want to consider prepending the document.querySelector('.${uniqueClass}').remove() code to the script, so it is guaranteed to run even if there is an error within the userland code (except in thec case of a SyntaxError).
I am not at all sure how useful it would be for script modules in general - AFAIK trying to import data from an inline script fails with CORS errors because script modules require retrieval from a network to work as documented.
Warning: this is a hack in response to a request for a hack, provided "as is" under the "don't sue me license" for your consideration.

Oh, that's a surprisingly simple solution which works fine for my use case. Thank you!

What do you mean by "script modules require retrieval from a network to work as documented"?

@Bergi I have never been able to get script modules to work using the file:// protocol, or been able find a syntax to import items from an inline script. If there are ways to do it I'll would be very happy to learn something new!
